# Event Listener not firing if element is updated afterward

Tags: javascript, events, listener

I wrote some custom audio controls in vanilla JS.  Everything works as expected, except for one thing.

First, my method:  I have a single audio element, and when a different song is selected, I pause the audio, update the audio element's sources, then run load() and play().

I have event listeners for the audio element as such:

```
audioElem.addEventListener('ended',updatePlayIcon);
audioElem.addEventListener('pause',updatePlayIcon);
audioElem.addEventListener('playing',updatePlayIcon);
```

I found that the pause event doesn't fire in the event that I am updating the audio element immediately afterward.  I don't understand it at all.

It's probably best just to look at the site.  http://joshblackburn-gregorythebold.rhcloud.com/albums

I had to add an explicit call to updatePlayIcon() in my function playTrack() because the pause method of the audo element isn't firing the event listener.

If it would be more helpful, I could write a minimal example showing the problem.

My question is this.  Why isn't the event listener firing if I update the audio element after the pause() method?

Here is a more simple demo of the problem.

```js
var tracks = ['https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f8/Stipa_demo.ogg', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c8/Example.ogg', 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f2/Median_test.ogg'];
audioContainer = document.getElementById('audio-container');
var audioElem = document.createElement('audio');
audioElem.controls = true;
audioElem.preload = "none";
var oggSource = document.createElement('source');
oggSource.type = "audio/ogg";
oggSource.src = tracks[0];
audioElem.appendChild(oggSource);
audioContainer.appendChild(audioElem);
var icon = document.getElementById('icon');


var getListItemByTrack = function(track) {
  return document.querySelector('li a[data-track="' + track + '"]');
};

audioElem.addEventListener('pause', function() {
  icon.innerHTML = "Paused";
  console.log(audioElem.dataset.track);
  getListItemByTrack(audioElem.dataset.track).className = "playLink paused";
});
audioElem.addEventListener('playing', function() {
  icon.innerHTML = "Playing";
  console.log(audioElem.dataset.track);
  getListItemByTrack(audioElem.dataset.track).className = "playLink playing";
});

var togglePlayPause = function() {
  var trackToPlay = this.dataset.track;
  var trackPlaying = audioElem.dataset.track;
  if (trackToPlay == trackPlaying) {
    if (audioElem.paused) {
      audioElem.play();
    } else {
      audioElem.pause();
    }
  } else {
    audioElem.pause();
    audioElem.dataset.track = this.dataset.track;
    oggSource.src = tracks[parseInt(audioElem.dataset.track)]
    audioElem.load();
    audioElem.play();
  }
};
var playLinks = document.getElementsByClassName("playLink");
for (var i = 0; i < playLinks.length; i++) {
  playLinks[i].addEventListener('click', togglePlayPause);
};
```

```css
.playLink {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.playing::after {
  content: " : playing";
}

.paused::after {
  content: " : paused";
}
```

```html
<div id="audio-container">
</div>
<div id="icon" class="material-icons">
  Ready
</div>
<ol>
  <li><a data-track="0" class="playLink">Play Track 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-track="1" class="playLink">Play Track 2</a></li>
  <li><a data-track="2" class="playLink">Play Track 3</a></li>
</ol>
```

If you click track 1 to play, you can keep clicking it to toggle play/pause and the pause event listener on the audio element fires, updating the list item's class (and therefor the :: after text).

However, if you click on Track 1, and while it's playing, click on track 2, it plays track 2, but track 1 never updates to paused, even though the pause() method is executed against the audio element.  The event listener isn't firing!

Comment: Post your code here, not just at a remote site. You can use [Stack Snippets](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) to make it executable.

Comment: The problem is that event listeners do not run immediately when you call `pause()` or `play()`. The events are added to the event queue, and the listeners all run after the Javascript returns. By that time, `audioElem.dataset.track` has been updated.

Comment: @Barmar, but it's not firing at all.  It's not just delayed.  If I add some console.log() messages in the listener function, they never appear at all.

Comment: Yeah, that wasn't quite right. It looks like `audoElem.load()` clears out the pending `pause` event. If you comment that out, you'll see all the console logs from both `pause` and `play`. But the `pause` event fires after `audoElem.dataset.track` is updated, so it logs the new track#.